# Reducing the CPU impact of producers on RabbitMQ

Tags: performance, rabbitmq

All,

I've been doing performance testing with RabbitMQ on a mid-grade desktop machine (5th-gen i3) and I've found that while my RabbitMQ can handle dozens of exchanges and even 100-200 queues & consumers fairly well, as soon as I start increasing the # of producers beyond ~30 the CPU usage very quickly goes to 100%. RAM usage is always acceptable (low hundreds of MB).
I'm sending various messages with sizes ranging from 400 bytes to 40kBytes, and interestingly this seems to have only a modest effect on CPU (just RAM).
I've been playing with messaging rates from my producers of between 1/second and 100/second, and this certainly has an effect on CPU but not nearly as much as the # of consumers. For example, 10 producers at 10msg/second is *MUCH* less of a load than 100 producers generating 1msg/second.
When CPU usage hits the wall I don't see any other red/yellow flags like max. # of Erlang processes, or file descriptor limits, in the RabbitMQ Admin console.

I'm currently using Python3 + Pika 0.10 and the BlockingConnection and Basic_Publish, and no specified delivery type for each of my producers (i.e. not durable). Is the highly asymmetric (and heavy) load from the producer side expected behavior?
Are there techniques I can use to reduced the load my producers put on my RabbitMQ instance?

Thanks and Regards